# "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite" problem. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, jdbc, driver

I changed my computer so I restarted entire process of connecting JDBC with DB using Driver. To shorten the story, I will post screenshots. Hope someone can help, as I have no idea what the problem is..

Step 1: I downloaded driver and stored it here:
[image]

Step 2: I went to InteliJ in File/ProjectStructure/Libraries and added exact same .jar file.
[image]

Step 3: After that I went to make a Connection with my db. It is located here:
[image]

Step 4: Lastly I coded following statement:

```
try {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Stefan\\people.db");
} catch (SQLException throwables) {
    throwables.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I get is no suitable driver found message. I double checked everything and still have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Are you using gradle/maven?

Comment: This is where I downloaded it: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.32.3.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency if you're using maven / gradle.

Example for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.32.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and for gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.32.3.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [sqlite3 jdbc driver](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.32.3.2/sqlite-jdbc-3.32.3.2.jar) in your classpath -- and run the application using `java -cp C:/Programming/Database/sqlite-jdbc-3.32.3.2.jar:. Main` if your classfile is named Main.class. If not substitute whatever it is named.